# Choosing a random XML node in VBscript

Tags: vbscript, xml-parsing, random-access

I have been having trouble figuring out how to choose a random xml node and store its text value into a variable.  I will be using the script in multiple instances and it will need to work regardless of the XML length.  The XML file is formatted like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <file>file path 1</file>
    <file>file path 2</file>
    <file>file path 3</file>
```

The code I have written is as follows:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.load("xmlfilepath") 
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file")
max = x.length
min=0
temp=(Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))
file = x[temp].nodeText

'do some things with the file path stored in the file variable.
```

I know I am doing something wrong but I have no idea what.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give me.

EDIT:
I am getting an error on line 7 char 9.  expected end of statement.

As for the "title" I didn't notice it was like that when I copied it overhere.  In my code it is "file".  I also fixed it in this edit.  but that wasn't part of my issue.

Comment: 1. What the _something wrong_ means? It's too broad term so we could guess only.  Some error message? Or unexpected behavior? 2. I can't see a tag named `"title"` in your `xml` file.

Comment: Change `[`square brackets`]` to `(`parentheses`)`, but it's a syntax error only; more to debug remain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In next script, comments `'#1`..`'#6` explain steps to debug your original code. All (debug only) `Wscript.Echo` statements could be removed.

```
' VB Script Document: launch under cscript
option explicit
On Error Goto 0

Dim xmlDoc, x, max, min, file, temp, xLoad

'#5 Initialize the random-number generator
' otherwise Rnd function keeps return the same only value 
randomize

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

'#1 ensure loading the document
xLoad = xmlDoc.load("D:\VB_scripts\SO\files_In\29285755.xml")
Wscript.Echo "parseError.errorCode " & xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode
If xLoad Then
    '#3 invalid property assignment
    ' x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file")
    set x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file")
    ' or   '     set x = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("/title/file")
    max = x.length
    min=0

    '#6  Object required: '[object]' error in line: file = x(temp).Text
    ' i.e. index out of bounds and zero based indexing and temp >= max 
    ' temp=(Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))
    temp=(Int((max-min)*Rnd+min))
    Wscript.Echo "max", max, "temp", temp, "temp>=max", CStr(temp >= max)

    '#4 Object doesn't support this property or method: 'nodeText'
    ' file = x(temp).nodeText
    file = x(temp).Text
Else
    '#2 descramble and resolve error in loading the document 
    ' parseError.errorCode -1072896683
    ' parseError.reason Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document
    ' i.e. the root element missing: added <title> 
    Wscript.Echo "parseError.reason " & xmlDoc.parseError.reason
    file = "N/A"
End If
Wscript.Echo file
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch !  The error code helped a ton.  Was able to figure out that my XML needed a top level tag that contained the file tags.  Thanks for letting me know about "randomize" and fixing the line 
    file = x(temp).text had that line all messed up.